# Android View with less height is flickering

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, border

I am creating border in recycle view elements using

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:background="@color/border" />
```

But when i use height 1px, its flicker while scroll the recycle view. I want less height/visible border but it's flickering.

Comment: You should avoid pixel sizes in general, and using values as small as 1 or 2 are subject to flickering since they might be rounded down to 0 / 1 pixel while rendering depending on their scroll position.

Comment: if i use 0.5dp, its also  flicker

Comment: Issue remains the same, you're probably using device with low DPI which resolves `0.5dp` to 1-2 pixel.

Comment: Okay i think then i need to play with  border color only, thanks